Where can I find an up-to-date map of Stockholm Central Station that shows the platform layout?
I have a rather tight transfer at Stockholm Central Station. While I've been there before, it's been a while, and I don't have a good mental grasp of the platform layout. As such, I tried to search for a map of it. I started with Jernhusen's page for Stockholm C, but the "Karta över stationen (Google)" link just leads to Google Maps which as far as I can tell doesn't show the platform layout. I can see the tracks, but it's not that helpful without the platform numbers labelled, especially as the station has multiple levels and Google Maps is a 2D plane.
Where can I find a map that actually shows the layout (including platform numbers) of Stockholm C?

Note: on google map you have different levels, e.g. I see there: 2, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4 (you can select it on the right). You may need to zoom in the station (and possibly you should select "direction" and "foot" to get the level (and it may take some seconds of navigation before google show it). But you can see different levels. -- Openstreet maps is often better for platform and public transportation (and stairs and passages), OTOH it is really just 2D

Note that there are also a number of trains going through Stockholm City which is quite close but actually separate, and platforms 1 to 4 exist at both.

@GiacomoCatenazzi I had the levels on my mobile but somehow they don't show up on desktop. That part of Google Maps is quite broken, it's very inconsistent when they show up or not. Also (especially in this case), it's really more for the shopping etc. than for the platforms and such. However it's unusual that Google maps does not show platform numbers, they are often visible in many other stations (though quite small).

OpenRailwayMap shows the platform numbers but good luck figuring out how to get to the platforms! The (OpenStreetMap-based but customized) map on the CFF website may be a bit clearer on the different passageways.

I'm not sure how much good a map will do a tourist, since a lot of this is underground and part of it in several levels. As a rule of thumb: for regular trains or Arlanda Express, enter through the main station building from Vasagatan and follow the signs. For commuter trains or the subway, you can enter in many ways from Vasagatan to Sergels Torg as described here: https://stockholmcity.nu/stockholm-central/. If you previously visited Stockholm some >8 years ago, the commuter train station is completely new as per 2016-2017 somewhere and in a different location.

@Lundin nice "3D" map of Stockholm City and metro stations, weird orientation though! I understand why someone added the North and South arrows by hand...

@jcaron Once you go down into these tunnels you lose all track of direction anyway :) Basically for the red or green subway lines, go down. For the blue subway line, go down down down. For the commuter trains, go down all the way to the center of the earth. :)

First of all, there are 3 interlinked stations, so be sure which you are transferring between: “Stockholm Central”/“Centralstation” for main-line trains (including the Arlanda Express); “Stockholm City” for commuter trains (Pendeltåg); and “T-Centralen” for the metro (T-bana).  “Stockholm C” usually means Stockholm Central, but occasionally gets (mis)used for Stockholm City.
If you’re just transferring between main-line trains, jcaron’s answer gives a good map of the platforms of Stockohlm Central.  The main station concourse building is on the west side of Vasagatan and south of Klarabergsviadukten; all platforms are clearly signed from there.  Platforms 1–10 are reached from the Vasagatan street level hall, while platforms 11–19 are reached from a lower level concourse below it.
If your change also involves the Pendeltåg or the T-bana, then the 3-dimensional diagram below is your friend.  The underground platforms are a bit of a warren, but signage is pretty decent.  In particular, signs towards the metro and Pendeltåg are very clear, so just follow those if that’s the way you’re going.  Signs towards the main-line Stockholm Centralstation from the T-bana/Pendeltåg are reasonably clear, and mostly will bring you into the lower level of the main station concourse (via the passage at the top-right of the diagram); all main-line platforms are reasonably signed from there.  A few signage routes may lead you to Stockholm C by some other entrance — e.g. the northern exit from the Pendeltåg or the metro blue line (bottom-right of the diagram, “Biljetthall Vasagatan”) has a passage bringing you up near platforms 1–3 (where the Arlanda Express goes from).
If you want any more details/advice, please tell us which trains/lines you’re transferring between, and I’m happy to elaborate further.


I'm transferring from train SJ train 2 to SJ train 12, but I don't think the specific platforms can be known this far in advance?

@Newbyte: Looking at these trains’ history (#2, #12), it seems #2 usually arrives at platform 18 or 19, and #12 usually leaves from platform 6.  Which is not the shortest change (I guess c. 5mins?), but all within the main station, so fairly straightforward and well signed: from platform 18/19 take the underpass back to the main lower-level concourse, then turn left and go up an escalator to the street-level hall, then follow signs ahead/leftward to platform 6.

@Newbyte Is that the night train from Malmö?  I got utterly lost when getting off that train, taking the stairs up to Klarabergsviadukten in September 2024, and it was a loooong way to where I needed to be.  I must have missed the underpass that PLL mentions. I suspect the night train arrives at platform 19 because it stays there for a little while and that platform is not used by departing commuter trains (just my hypothesis).

I got off platform 19 here 5 minutes after waking up, and was indeed very confused how to get to the "normal" part of the station!

@gerrit: Yes, I’ve made a very similar mistake! Its fine once  you know roughly what you’re looking for — stairs/lift down to an underpass not up, and from near the middle of the platform — but if you’re not sure then the Klarabergsviadukten stairs are very deceptively confusing!

For the general layout, here's what OpenRailwayMap shows:

You can see platforms 1-7 to the North of the station and platforms 10-19 to the West. A bit further to the East you can see Stockholm City's platforms 1-4.
While there's no map (and you'll probably have to look at Google Maps, OpenRailwayMap, OpenStreetMap, or the CFF map to build a mental picture), the always useful Man in Seat 61 has a page dedicated to Stockholm Central.
Here's the summary:


Platforms 1 & 2 are dead-end platforms at the far northern end of the station used by the Arlanda Express to the airport.  It takes a few minutes to walk from the main hall through the food court to the area where these trains stop.
Platforms 3-7 are also dead-end platforms, at the northern end of the station beyond the food court, though not as far as 1 & 2.
Platform 8 is the northern end part of platform 10, accessed from platform 10.
There is no platform 9.
Platform 10 is right next to the main hall to the west, accessed through the doors directly beneath the main departures board.
Platforms 11-19 are also to the west of the main hall, go down the escalators to the lower level, then along the underpass beneath all the tracks and up steps or a lift up to the relevant platform.


It then goes on to give a lot of information on the various platforms, and includes many pictures of inside the station that may be helpful.
Remember that there is another train station, "Stockholm City", which also has platforms 1 to 4, and is nearby, but is an actually separate station (as seen on the map above). Double-check which of the two stations each of your trains uses. Commuter trains use the City station, not Central, for instance.

I found this: https://fråga.tågexperterna.nu/hur-hittar-man-pa-stockholms-central/
In short you reach track 1-10 from Vasagatan street level but 11-19 requires passing under or over the tracks.
